# Does catch (...) work on throw; with no object?

Tags: c++, exception, try-catch, throw, ellipsis

What does C++ standard say should happen for the following code when there is no pending exception being processed higher up the stack?

```
try {
  throw;
} catch (...) {
  cerr << "Caught exception." << endl;
}
```

Will the throw with no object be caught or not?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From the 2003 C++ Standard §15.1[except.throw]/8:

> If  no  exception  is  presently  being  handled,  executing  a  *throw-expression*  with  no  operand  calls `terminate()`.

So, in your example, since no exception is currently being handled, nothing is thrown and instead `terminate()` is called.  Since `terminate()` does not return, your `catch` block will never be entered.

Comment: … Do not pass `throw;` do not collect exception `$200`.