# c++ exception naked throw

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, exception, try-catch

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between throw and throw with arg of caught exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1481612/what-is-the-difference-between-throw-and-throw-with-arg-of-caught-exception)
>   [Does catch (…) work on throw; with no object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5766006/does-catch-work-on-throw-with-no-object)

This will crash:

```
try
{
    if(1)
        throw;
}
catch(...)
{
    printf("hi");
}
```

I thought I could do that but I guess not. What is the right way to throw when you don't need any information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <exception>

try
{
    if(1)
        throw std::exception();
}
catch(...)
{
    printf("hi");
}
```

This might be better, depending on what you are up to:

```
class my_exception : public std::exception {};
```

then,

```
try
{
    if(1)
        throw my_exception();
}
catch(my_exception)
{
    printf("hi");
}
```

Answer (score 6):

A "naked throw" re-throws an exception that has already been caught. Doesn't work well if there is nothing to rethrow.

You can really throw anything, like `throw "Error!";`, even if that is not too useful. You could otherwise try

```
if (x == 1)
    throw std::runtime_error("x == 1 is not a good value here")`.
```

Comment: I'm not going to use the throw information though. Is there some standard practice for that maybe like `throw std::defaultthrow`?

Comment: You *should* use the exception though. `catch(...)` is basically worthless as you will have no idea how to recover from "any" exception. If you insist on a completely generic exception type though, you have the option of simple types like `throw false;`, or use the standard `std::runtime_error()`.